# Split Excel cell rows into columns

Tags: excel

**I have an excel database that goes like this:**

```
football team name

football team secretary

football team secretary email

football team name

football team secretary

football team secretary email

football team name

football team secretary

football team secretary email
```

---

**i need for the database to look this this:**

```
football team name | football team secretary | football team secretary email

football team name | football team secretary | football team secretary email

football team name | football team secretary | football team secretary email
```

---

I have tried doing this by using a text filter but the data messed up, is there any way at all to do this? It seems impossible to me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)put data on sheet2
b) use formulas shown in word table on sheet1
c) results are shown on sheet1
HTH
[![word formulas ][https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4jvW.jpg]][Sheet2display]

Answer (score 0):

Where `List` is your range of original data in a single column, enter the following formula in some cell:

```
=INDEX(List,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)*3)+COLUMNS($A:A))
```

Fill right for three columns, then select the row and fill down as far as needed.

[image]